# SUPEE-11086 Missing patches for magento versions

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-11086

I don't see a patch for 1.9.0.1 is this an error by the magento team or is it not supported?

Answer (score 3):

Patch is supported for your version.Apply the patch `PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.1.0_v1.sh`. I was using Magento 1.9.3.7, applied `PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.3.10_v1.sh`. The patch was applied successfully. I was also confused earlier tried both 1.9.2.4 and 1.9.3.10 where the second was applied successfully which does it mean the patch can be applied for versions 1.9.2.5 to 1.9.3.10.

So I hope for you too `PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.1.0_v1.sh` can be applied from versions 1.7.0.3 to 1.9.1.0

Comment: I can confirm that PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.1.0_v1.sh works for 1.8.0.0. thanks for the tip!