# Mage::log() not working on new Magento update (1.9.4.1)

Tags: magento-1.9, log, bug, magento-1.9.4.1

After this new update (1.9.4.1), Mage::log() is not working. Apparently, it has something to do with `Zend_Validate_File_Extension` on line 819 at Mage.php where it checks if the file `is_readable()` before it even exists. I reversed the whole `log()` method to its previous version and it is working again.

What is the main channel that i can contact Magento team to report this issue?

Comment: I would start @ https://magentocommeng.slack.com/
Have you try to reproduce this issue on a clean 1.9.4.1 version of Magento 1?

Comment: @PiotrSiejczuk I have the same problem. The issue is in `Mage::log` and the Zend Framework. If you look in the file and the line mentioned, and in `app/Mage.php` on line 827, it should be quite that non existent files will not get logged to. This is a problem for anyone who rotates their log files.

Comment: Depends on rotation rules and policies. You can rotate logs but keep original file (so the exception will not be thrown). Anyhow: I would suggest to check with Community PPL and Slack

Comment: @PiotrSiejczuk I've just tried it on a fresh installation. Still not working. Btw, how can I access that magento slack channel?

Comment: @PiotrSiejczuk That doesn't work for new log files. Your second comment implies that the ability to change log rotation configuration makes this not a serious issue and I completely disagree. Your first comment implies that this is probably only a problem for OP, or in some sort of edge case, and I very much disagree with that, too. I completely understand why Magento would not have noticed this bug, but these implications are the opposite of what is needed here (whether they are deliberate or not).

Comment: There are many situations where this is problematic: clean installs (in this case the system.log does not yet exist), creation/installation of local and third-party modules that log to custom log files, logrotate configurations that do not explicitly create/keep the original log file.

Comment: Yeah, logging is essential to every software, I wonder why they've let that pass. My dream is that when 2020 comes and Magento team stop supporting 1.x, they upload their last version to an official Git repo so that the community can keep it up to date

Comment: @cslogic "My dream is that when 2020 comes and Magento team stop supporting 1.x, they upload their last version to an official Git repo so that the community can keep it up to date" => Already done with OpenMage LTS : https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts

Comment: @toon81: I totally agree with you. There seems to be a similar discussion within Slack. I have asked some Gents from Magento, if they are aware / have reports about this issue from different sources...

Comment: @FrédéricMARTINEZ thats funny, Ben Marks actually told me about that repo about 30 min before I read you comment.. Thanks anyway, will take a look at it

Answer (score 7):

<s>Official patch incoming :)</s> Still waiting for official patch ... :(

> *piotrekkaminski commented 13 hours ago*
>
> This is the current official patch that will be ported to earlier versions (this should work on latest) https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/0596cae2d25bf467edbd3d3f03ab9f8f

<sup>Source: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/648#issuecomment-480941871</sup>

Answer (score 7):

I'll summarize everything I found so far based on research and interaction with Magento both support and Slack in regards to patching with SUPEE-11086. What can be done:

UPDATE 2: The issue is resolved in the next PATCH SUPEE-11155 - https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-11155. As always before applying the patch check for the possible issues thread - [Security Patch SUPEE-11155 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279571/security-patch-supee-11155-possible-issues) Thanks goes to [Aad Mathijssen](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268229/magelog-not-working-on-new-magento-update-1-9-4-1/269357?noredirect=1#comment399738_269357) for the great comment.

Update: An official patch is available on demand for EE version. Basically, it's Piotr Kaminski's gist wrapped as Magento patch file.

1. Delete changes for `app/Mage.php` in the patch file. This is what I have done so far.
   Pros - logging works as before.
   Cons - editing a patch file, logging is unprotected from a possible exploit (but this should be very low risk). When Magento releases an official fix you will have to revert it and apply original unedited Patch.
2. Add another patch on top based on Piotr Kaminski's gist - https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/0596cae2d25bf467edbd3d3f03ab9f8f. Piotr Kaminski is part of Magento in charge of security, so this comes straight from the horse's mouth. Gist was shared in Magento slack and will probably end as SUPEE-11086 v1.1.
   Pros - This is the Magento way
   Cons - You will have to wait for this to become official, or take responsibility and package it as patch yourself, which will bring you back to having to revert once an official patch is up.
   A slight variation would be instead of adding two patches to edit the original one with those changes.
3. Edit `Zend_Validate_File_Extension::isValid` and remove file existence validation. there is a long discussion in Magento LTS github - https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/648. The `isValid` method does things it's not expected to do, so some members propose to fix it. My opinion is that this is not a good solution, yes code is bad, but it was there forever and may be used in custom modules/code. On the contrary, the worst that can happen is that files are not checked for existence.
   Pros - a rather simple fix
   Cons - changes a library file and amends its functionality.
   You can apply this either as a custom patch or by rewriting the whole class in `local` code pool.

I chose to edit the patch, and when a v1.1 comes I'll revert the edited patch, and apply original version and after that fix. This suits well our build process and internal policy, it might be different for you. No matter what you chose it's better to apply this patch sooner than later.

Comment: As of the June 25, Magento has released SUPEE-11155, Magento Commerce 1.14.4.2 and Magento Open Source 1.9.4.2 that include a fix for this issue. Essentially, the patch by Piotr Kaminski has been included.

Answer (score 4):

Something from Community Inputs. There is a new Validator is used Zend_Validate_File_Extension as per below:

https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/blob/master/CE1.9/PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.4.0_v1-2019-03-26-03-05-04.sh#L183

"The solution is editing the patch and just removing the changes from app/Mage.php I would strongly discourage this practice, but the situation is critical".

Comment: It is indeed a bad practice, but I can't survive without logging. Hope Adobe can fix it soon

Comment: yeah i had to recreate all the log files because logrotator script was deleting files and creating zips of them. I will need to find a better script of magento doesnt fix thi.

Comment: @KalvinKlien: Did you try with: copytruncate option of logrotate?

"Truncate the original log file to zero size in place after creating a copy, instead of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new one. It can be used when some program cannot be told to close its logfile and thus might continue writing (appending) to the previous log file forever. Note that there is a very small time slice between copying the file and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost. When this option is used, the create option will have no effect, as the old log file stays in place".

Comment: Thanks @PiotrSiejczuk! I used this: /path/var/log/*log {
rotate 7
copytruncate
daily
compress
missingok
notifempty
}

Answer (score 1):

My temporary solution was to copy `lib/Zend/Validate/File/Extension.php` to `app/code/local/Zend/Validate/File/Extension.php` and **remove** this part of the code from `isValid()` method:

```
    // Is file readable ?
    #require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
    if (!Zend_Loader::isReadable($value)) {
        return $this->_throw($file, self::NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

It would become...

```
public function isValid($value, $file = null)
{
    if ($file !== null) {
        $info['extension'] = substr($file['name'], strrpos($file['name'], '.') + 1);
    } else {
        $info = pathinfo($value);
...
```

When Magento 1.9.4.2 is released I check that again.

In fact, the file not being readable, or doesn't exist, doesn't mean that the file name is not valid, right?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to do not change core code and use an update like this (https://gist.github.com/mehdichaouch/99c67298b5a65f81219c9b69942b6fe7)

```php
$installer->run("
    INSERT INTO `{$installer->getTable('core_config_data')}` (scope, scope_id, path, value)
    VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/log/allowedFileExtensions', 'log,txt,html,csv')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 'log,txt,html,csv';
");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another issue (which may be deliberate from the Magento team) which prevents the ability to write log files inside subfolders. For example:

```php
Mage::log('Some log information', Zend_Log::DEBUG, 'somefolder/anotherfolder/somelogfile.log', true);
```

In earlier versions, that call would have created a file at location:

`/your-magento-app-root-folder/var/log/somefolder/anotherfolder/somelogfile.log`

But since there is a `basename()` function call in `Mage::log()` method, the file is written at:

`/your-magento-app-root-folder/var/log/somelogfile.log`.

Here is the incriminated code in `app/Mage.php`:

```php
$file = empty($file) ?
    (string) self::getConfig()->getNode('dev/log/file', Mage_Core_Model_Store::DEFAULT_CODE) : basename($file);
```

Even if it is not especially related to 1.9.4.1, the issue started to happen recently (around latest 1.9.3.x versions) and is very annoying when you have to deal with a lot of log files, sometimes with the same name (but initially in different subfolders).

As that piece of code is probably deliberate from Magento team, I think there is no plan to fix it in a further release, which implies to hack it to restore the initial behavior...

Comment: For that subfolder issue I have no clue, but for the actual logging problem we are standing for that piece of code https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/0596cae2d25bf467edbd3d3f03ab9f8f