# Magento 1.9.2.0 problem with patch SUPEE-11086

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-11086

I have been having the below error when I try to patch my Magento store 1.9.2.0

`patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 190.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml.rej` Could I get some help with this please?
Thanks

Comment: Try to delete the file `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml` and patch again. Make a backup of it first.

Comment: @Black Do I add the file `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml` once the patch is successful please?

Comment: Maybe add your problem here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267490/security-patch-supee-11086-possible-issues

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the file `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml` on my server had been edited manually, `<pdf>1</pdf>` had been added to the list

`<allowed>
<jpg>1</jpg>
<jpeg>1</jpeg>
<png>1</png>
<gif>1</gif>
</allowed>`

So I uploaded a fresh copy of file `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml` applied the patch then added the previous changes. Everything works fine now. Thank @Black